# Django - Testing model field change

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, django-testing

Suppose a model field defaults to `None` and a method after some complex action is expected to change the field to `None`.

At the end of a test, I do `assertEqual` and the field is `None` as expected. What if the method failed silently and the `None` wasn't a result of the method's action but merely a coincidence?

Is there a way to determine a model field change without having to set a different value at the beginning of the test?

In my case it'd be a `ForeignKey` field to a complex object from another package.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been open for quite some time and I'm not sure you even need an answer anymore, but I found it while searching for something else yesterday and I got some free time now, so...

I'm not an expert and it may not actually serve your specific need, but seems to me like you need a mocking library. Michael Foord's [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock) is one of the favorites.

What you could do is use `mock.patch` as a decorator or context manager to mock the attribute you're trying to test, like this:

```
def test_attribute_is_being_set_to_none():
    mocked_attribute = mock.PropertyMock()
    with mock.patch('MyModule.MyClass.attribute_to_mock', mocked_attribute)
        MyObject = MyClass()
        MyObject.method()

    p.assert_called_with(None)
```

This is supposed to test if the attribute was ever set to `None` while you were testing. If you want to be more rigid, you could use `assert_called_once_with(None)` to see if the object was only set once during the method.

You may run into some troubles with mocking the attribute, namespaces, using decorators or context managers... that depends on a lot of things, but I'm pretty sure mocking is the way to go here.